# c++ float to string

Tags: c++, floating-point

Does C++ have ANY mechanism (function or whatever) to convert a float (or double) to the representation that maintains both precision of a number and also a minimal length of the number? I mean something like JavaScript does.

It looks like C++ is not willing to do so, for example:

- std::to_string(1.23456789e10); // returns "12345678900.000000" (unnecessary zeros)
- (std::ostringstream() << 1.23456789e10).str() // returns "1.234567e10" (two digits lost)
- snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", 1.23456789e10); // as above

Comment: [#include <iomanip>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Comment: What's wrong with `setprecision()`?

Comment: For that input, what is the expected output (keeping in mind that the actual number might not be exactly representable by a floating point type)?

Comment: `"%g"` -- Even when using `snprintf`, the format specifier has options to control how the number is displayed.  You must have stumbled across this, as you knew to use `%g`.

Comment: And what is the actual and underlying problem you try to solve? Why are the strings you get not solving that problem?

Comment: If you can use C++20, forget about printf and stream options : Use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter

Comment: No it does not. There is some history here. C and C++ predate the time when efficient algorithms existed to do a accurate and minimal conversion. So some standard library implementations do not always convert in the most optimal manner. Compiler writers are apparently unwilling to make backwardly incompatible changes in this area, so the C++ standard has never been updated to require accurate conversions. Your best bet would be to use a library that can perform this conversion such as google's [double-conversion](https://github.com/google/double-conversion).

Comment: Some background. The OP is asking for a floating-point conversion that is accurate (so the reverse conversion reproduces the original number) and uses a minimum number of digits (so just outputting say 25 significant digits is not a solution). This is a surprisingly hard problem and the discovery of efficient algorithms is relatively recent.

Comment: Thank you @john, this is the answer I actually know, but wanted some good programmer to confirm it.

Comment: A library that might do what you want, Ryū: https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu

Comment: "float to string" and "convert a float (or double) to the representation that maintains both precision of a number and also a sensible length of the number?" --> Yes. `std::cout << std::hexfloat << fp << '\n'` and `std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<decltype(fp)>::max_digits10) << fp << std::endl;`

Comment: colleagues, so many questions and so many negative points but no help shown.
This is actually very useful question so please read carefully.
*** iomanip - yeah, I know the header, how it could help?
*** setprecission, "%g.*" - for both cases you need to manually set the precision while I would like to have it automatic. Same result as in JavaScript as I described.
*** C++20 formatter is cool, but g++ does not have it implemented yet.

Comment: *** std::to_string produces invalid outputs for many cases.
*** and yeah there is std::to_chars in C++23 (in future) - yet another remake of existing solutions not solving anything now. And there will be much more similar stuff in further releases of C++, bot nothing I could use
*** External library? Sure, why not! Boost even. Isn't that overkill anyways?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yeah, but for 0.123 it will add so many unnecessary zeros...

Comment: @noonespecial "add so many unnecessary zeros" --> That is not part of the question. The question's stated goal was "and also a sensible length of the number".  _Sensible_, not _minimal_.  Still sensible IMO with up to `max_digits10`  trailing zeroes.  Otherwise look to `sprintf(buf, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, fp)` or its C++ equivalent, if any.  Why is removing trailing zeroes important?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "Sensible, not minimal." -> fair enough. Thanks for indication.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just checked what you said and it will actually print the minimal length if we use std::ios_base& defaultfloat( std::ios_base& str ); This looks exactly like the thing that I was looking for! I've tested this and it actually works! Without your help I wouldn't look into this! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is not that obvious but actually Yes. Here I share the code that converts fundamental types to std::string maintaining precision and relatively short representation of float and double types.

```
    template <typename Type>
    constexpr static std::string toString(Type value) noexcept
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;

        if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<typename std::remove_cv<Type>::type>::value)
            oss << std::defaultfloat << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<Type>::digits10 + 1);

        oss << value;
        return oss.str();
    }
```

Now some background. The code above is based on `std::ostringstream`. You may think why the above implementation is better than `std::to_string` for example? Moreover, why not other methods as C++ provides actually a lot of different methods offering similar stuff. Ok then, lets walk through each method:

- `std::string`: First of all it may produce invalid outputs. Especially for small values of `float` and `double` [source](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-discussion/c/6xhWgsEuvPo). Moreover it appends lots of unnecessary zeros for example for 1.23456789e10 input the function produces "12345678900.000000".
- `snprintf` with `"%g"` specifier. It produces either `"%f"` or `"%e"` whatever is shorter. Unfortunately reduces precision while it could be preserved. For example, the 1.23456789e10 produces "1.234567e10". Also if you'd manually specify the precision, it will either add unnecessary zeros or remove less significant digits. We would like to have something that automatically maintains the precision and short length of the string
- `std::format`: Omg, I was waiting years for this function. Unfortunately, as of today only MSVC and clang implements the  header and it is still missing in g++.
- `std::to_chars`: Feature of C++23, not existing yet. Looks like another remake of `std::to_string`.
- Any use of third party libraries - came on! For just a such purpose it would be an overkill.

`std::ostringstream` by itself does not keep the accuracy of a number. For example the 1.23456789e10 produces "1.234567e10". It requires to specify `std::setprecision` along with the `std::defaultfloat` to maintain the precision and relatively short (user friendly) representation. For more information please refer to the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). And it is not that obvious in general - for more information please refer to the [source](https://youtu.be/kw-U6smcLzk).

**Important note:** The code is not exactly maintaining the precision as stated above. This was done on purpose. If you look carefully the `std::numeric_limits<Type>::digits10` is "number of decimal digits that can be represented without change" while `std::numeric_limits<Type>::max_digits10` is "number of decimal digits necessary to differentiate all values of this type". Therefore, you need by your own decide what exactly you need. In case you are presenting a number to the user the `digits10` is the most "user friendly" representation (0.3f is "0.3" for float), however only `max_digits10` will give you the exact representation (0.3f is "0.300000012" for float). Thank you Eric for indicating this!

Comment: This does not produce the desired results. For `.1+.2`, the result should be “0.30000000000000004”, because, due to rounding, the `double` result of `.1+.2` is slightly above the `double` closest to .3. For example, JavaScript “console.log(.1+.2)` produces “0.30000000000000004”. [However, the code in this answer produces “0.3”.](https://godbolt.org/z/4eP7Eo9v5)

Comment: For another example, for the exactly representable value 123.834756380650873097692965529859066009521484375, the result should be “123.83475638065087”. But the code in this answer produces “123.8347563806509”. That value is nearer 123.8347563806509015194023959338665008544921875, so accuracy has been lost.

Comment: Hi @EricPostpischil. This is a very good indication! Thank you so much!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have added "important note" referring to what you said fixing the issue. Thank you so much!